# KERAS: AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim' , Tensorflow image segmentation demo does not work on my anaconda

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, kaggle

I know there is an issue with the line:

```
history = model.fit(train_ds,
                   steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(num_train_examples / float(batch_size))),
                   epochs=epochs,
                   validation_data=val_ds,
                   validation_steps=int(np.ceil(num_val_examples / float(batch_size))),
                   callbacks=[cp])
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'

and am using tensorflow's demo : image segmentation.
I think it's to do with the input dimensions but can't find a way out of the problem.

Information for database:

```
train_ds = get_baseline_dataset(x_train_filenames,
                                y_train_filenames,
                                preproc_fn=tr_preprocessing_fn,
                                batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = get_baseline_dataset(x_val_filenames,
                              y_val_filenames, 
                              preproc_fn=val_preprocessing_fn,
                              batch_size=batch_size)
   

def get_baseline_dataset(filenames, 
                         labels,
                         preproc_fn=functools.partial(_augment),
                         threads=5, 
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         shuffle=True):
```

(ps. it works in Google colab but just not on anaconda/spyder)

Comment: running on python 3.6 , anaconda, and spyder

Comment: can you share the details related to your train_ds and val_ds? Difficult to pin point where the problem is otherwise

Comment: @kvish  i just edited the question with the details

Comment: I just took a look at the image segmentation notebook.
Does the code corresponding to this block run on your system:
temp_ds = get_baseline_dataset(x_train_filenames, 
                               y_train_filenames,
                               preproc_fn=tr_preprocessing_fn,
                               batch_size=1,
                               shuffle=False)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54945768/14290244) comment helps to solve your problem. Thanks!