# TensorFlow dataset from list of images in keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to understand how to read local images, use them as TensorFlow [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and train Keras model with TF Dataset. I'm following TF Keras MNIST TPU [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/keras_mnist_tpu.ipynb). The only difference that I want to read my set of images and train on them.

Let's say I have list of images (file names) and corresponding list of labels.

```
files = [...] # list of file names
labels = [...] # list of labels (integers)
images = tf.constant(files) # or tf.convert_to_tensor(files)
labels = tf.constant(labels) # or tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(files))
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function).batch(batch_size)
```

The `parse_function` is a simple function which reads the input file name and yields the image data and corresponding label, e.g.

```
def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, label
```

At this point I have a `dataset` which is a tf.data.Dataset type (more precisely tf.data.BatchDataset) and I pass it along to keras model `trained_model` from [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/keras_mnist_tpu.ipynb), e.g.

```
history = trained_model.fit(dataset, ...)
```

But at this point code breaks with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

The error comes from keras which performs the check on given input like that

```
from keras import backend as K
K.is_tensor(dataset) # which returns false
```

Keras tries to determine type of the input and since it is not a tensor it assumes it is numpy array and tries to get its dimension. That's why the error occurs.

My questions here are the following:

- am I reading TF dataset correctly? I looked up plenty of examples on internet and it seems I'm reading it as people suggest
- why my dataset is not a tensor? may be I need to perform additional conversion, but it is not the case of TF [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/keras_mnist_tpu.ipynb)
- why in TF [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/keras_mnist_tpu.ipynb) everything works with tf datasets, I really don't see any difference from they way how they read MNIST data (which is in different data-format, but eventually they get images) and what I'm doing here.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Please note, even TF [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/keras_mnist_tpu.ipynb) is about TPUs it is structured such that it works on both TPUs and CPU/GPUs.

Comment: Are your labels generated similar to whats given in the tutorial? Do have them read from a file separately or generated according to the files? have you one hot encoded them?

Comment: I generated labels on my own. But as I explained in my answer to my post the real issue was in using keras vs tf.keras model. The usage of later solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in using Keras model. The example in TF tutorial relies on Keras model build using tf.keras module (all layers, model, etc. came from tf.keras). While the model I was using (DenseNet) relies on pure keras module, i.e. all layers came from keras module and not from tf.keras. This cause the tf.data.Dataset to be checked for ndim in fit method of keras model. Once I adjusted my DenseNet to use tf.keras layers everything become working again.